# Determining semantic measures of concepts between two different ontologies using SML

Tags: java, ontology, semantics

I need to semantically match two ontology concepts using [SML library](http://www.semantic-measures-library.org/sml/index.php). [Here](http://www.semantic-measures-library.org/sml/index.php?q=show_source&src=./docs/sources/slib/examples/sml/owl/SMComputationOWL.java) is the sample code they've provided which only compares two concepts of the same ontology.

I have also tried it loading two ontologies into the program creating another `GraphMemory`. But we cannot get a result as it has this `compare` method in SM_Engine class which compares two concepts in the same ontology and we cannot use concepts of different ontologies in that method to compare.

`SM_Engine engine = new SM_Engine(g);
 double sim = engine.compare(sMconf, threatURI, cropURI);
 System.out.println("Similarity : " + sim);`

This gives a similarity measure as a double value. But it is between two concepts of the same ontology.

The following exception is thrown when URIs of different ontologies are added to `compare` method as parameters.

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The given URI <the URI of the other ontology concept> cannot be associated to a class
    at slib.sml.sm.core.engine.SM_Engine.throwErrorIfNotClass(SM_Engine.java:1185)
    at slib.sml.sm.core.engine.SM_Engine.compare(SM_Engine.java:698)
    at com.ontoger.core.main.SMComputationOWL.main(SMComputationOWL.java:76)`

What I want is to get a semantic similarity measure of two concepts in two different ontologies. Is there a way to do this using SML?